# Using Alarm manager to start a Service every X minutes off the main thread?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am currently using an AlarmManager in my activity to start a service every X minutes.

It's seems to work but it looks as if the Service runs initially on the main thread which I believe to cause random ANRs. (this was determined using some code snippet to check the looper, the only true value returned is when the service starts (which then starts Asynctasks))

How can I use the AlarmManager to start the Service on its own thread?

Or should I be starting this repeating Service in some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use the AlarmManager to start the Service on its own thread?

`AlarmManager` does not affect your threads. *You* need to arrange for *your* service to do its work on a background thread. The simplest way to do this is to extend `IntentService` and put your work in `onHandleIntent()`.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks for the pointer. Added to this, what would be a reason that a call back from the Service (that's picked up in the activity) stop working? I think there is a broadcast receiver, does it need anything in the manifest? (im not 100% as it's been a while and other people have chipped in on the coding)

Comment: @MrPablo: "I think there is a broadcast receiver, does it need anything in the manifest?" -- if you are using a system broadcast to pass information from a service to a (possibly non-existent) activity, you're doing it wrong. Use an in-process event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.).

Comment: The activity is in fact always there (the app runs 24/7).but I'll take a look at what you mentioned. So using the AlarmManager is OK? Just wondering if there was a better way to achieve this.

Comment: @MrPablo: "So using the AlarmManager is OK?" -- `AlarmManager` is fine for an every X minutes bit of work, yes. It's just not involved with the threading model of the work itself

Comment: But once I fix that with your suggestion it should be fine? It's the only thing so far I can see that may cause an ANR, as all my network stuff is done in Asynctasks

Comment: @MrPablo: An `AsyncTask` makes no sense in a service. The point behind a service is to *not* do *anything* on the main application thread, and the point behind an `AsyncTask` is to do *some* things on the main application thread (e.g., `onPostExecute()`). Use `IntentService`. Or use regular threads. Whatever the means, you have to arrange to get your service work on a background thread.

Comment: Funny you mention it, I asked about this somewhere else and was pointed to IntentServices. What's the difference  exactly? They sound like they would be better, because the "service"  does only need do run when the app is in use

Comment: @MrPablo: You can think of `IntentService` as being a quasi-direct replacement for `AsyncTask`, insofar as both do their main work on a background thread and both are "fire and forget" (they shut themselves down when the work is done). `IntentService` is a `Service`, which serves as a marker to the OS that you're doing work and the OS should not be trigger-happy about terminating your process to free up memory for other processes.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Would it be correct then to use the IntentService to do my network Asynctasks? (I am downloading images from a server) Can I get a callback as well, so I can trigger something in the activity?

Comment: @MrPablo: You are welcome to do network I/O in `onHandleIntent()` of an `IntentService`. Your "callback" is "the network I/O is done", and your code in `onHandleIntent()` can signal your UI layer via one of the aforementioned event bus implementations.